# Passing javascript values into JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to achieve this functionality using ternary operator. Here iconElement is an
javascript variable contains JSX. I am getting error like this (Screenshot included).
How to achieve this?[image]

```
<div className = 'InputFieldGroup'>

    {
        inputField ? inputField : 
            {iconElem}
            <input
                {...otherProps}
                className = 'InputField'
                value = {value}
                onChange = {clicked}
                autoComplete = 'off' />
        
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error before while using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Conditional):

```
<div className="InputFieldGroup">
  {inputField ? (
    inputField
  ) : (
    <>
      {iconElem}
      <input
        {...otherProps}
        className="InputField"
        value={value}
        onChange={clicked}
        autoComplete="off"
      />
    </>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: I want to execute both iconElem variable and input field only when ternary condition is false

Comment: You can only return a single React element, therefore you should add a fragment, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If the input field should be visible in both cases I would do something like this instead to avoid having to duplicate components:

```js
<div className="InputFieldGroup">
   {!inputField && iconElem}
      <input
        {...otherProps}
        className="InputField"
        value={value}
        onChange={clicked}
        autoComplete="off"
      />
  )}
</div>
```